# ReactJS + React::shouldComponentUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня появился вопрос по методу `React::shouldComponentUpdate()`, т.к. поведение его мне не понятно.

У меня есть состояние **A**, это массив объектов. Я меняю состояние через `this.setState()` и назначаю какому нибудь объекту новое значение свойства.

Но в `React::shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState), nextState === this.state`

Как такое может быть? Я хочу обновлять компонент только когда что-то в `nextState` не будет равно чему-то в `this.state`.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, отрисуется всё-равно только изменившееся в DOM, но если действительно нужно оптимизировать сам цикл обновления, проверьте что вы делаете так:

```
...
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextState.someValue !== this.state.someValue;
},
...
```

Из кода в задаче не совсем понятно, но похоже что вы пытаетесь сравнить два объекта. А они, в javascript, не являясь ссылкой на один и тот-же, всегда будут не идентичны, даже если их свойства - равны, и вероятно в этом проблема.

А `shouldComponentUpdate` сделан специально, чтобы рендерить компонент только при изменении нужного свойства (или свойств) состояния `this.state`.

Comment: Долго описывать то что я пытаюсь сравнить. Просто представьте себе массив объектов в состоянии и при клике на ссылку, в состоянии меняется свойство какого нибудь объекта. Далее при shouldComponentUpdate состоянии this.state.obj[123].name == nextState.obj[123].name
Проблема в идентичности значений в этом методе :/

Comment: похоже, вам надо дописать код, но лучше сделайте jsBin, там можно проверить, а тут и в камент не влезет большой кусок

Comment: Уточните, как вы меняете это значение

Comment: `var state = $.extends({}, this.state);
state.obj[123].name = 'test';
this.setState(state);`